# mySQL nested loop wont execute

Tags: java, mysql, sql, web-services, nested-loops

I'm working on a SOAP based webservice where in a part of it i have to perform some queries on the database using nested loop, the problem is that the inner loop just gets executed for ONE time only, before giving up.This is the code:

```
          for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
                for(int j=0; j<sintom.length;j++){
                    var[(i*sintom.length)+j] = "INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta,  descrizione, sesso, etnia, sintomi) "
                + "VALUES ('" + malattia + "','" + eta + "','" + descrizione + "','" +  sexarra[0] + "','" + selec[i] + "','" + sintom[j] + "')";
        }

      }
```

This is where the queries are supposed to get executed:

```
        if (errore.equals("")) {
              try {
                    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
      for(int i=0; i<selec.length; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<sintom.length;j++){

                     st.executeUpdate(var[(i*sintom.length)+j]);}}
```

What happens is that no matter the size of **select** it will work fine as long as the length of **sintom** is 1,bigger than 1 and it wont work.

Thanks for your expert advices, always appreciated!

Comment: Try creating a different `Statement` object for each query.  Also, fix your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Could you elaborate abit more? You mean i should create statement inside the loops? How could i protect myself against SQL injection?

Comment: Yes, create the statement object, execute the query, and then destroy the object -- for *each* query.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115739/sql-injection-in-java-mysql-multiple-queries) and the corresponding answer for details on using prepared statements to secure yourself against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks alot, ill be back after implementing what you advised.

Comment: @cdhowie: the idea of a prepared statement is to reuse it multiple times with different parameters. This is where it becomes more efficient than a regular statement. It shouldn't be destroyed and recreated for each query. It's always a good idea to use them even for one-shot queries to avoid SQL injections, though.

Comment: Indeed, and this query is an excellent candidate for that... however, based on the details posted it appears that reusing a `Statement` object is causing the problem in the first place.  Maybe prepared statement objects behave a bit differently in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Your use-case is a perfect example of a case where a prepared statement should be used. Read more about them in [the JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

Using a prepared statement would allow

- avoiding SQL injection attacks. You should never use string concatenation to build your SQL query. A malicious user could enter some special value which would completely change the meaning of your query. A non-malicious user could enter special characters (quotes, for example) which would make the query fail because it's not syntaxically correct.
- letting the database prepare the execution plan only once, for all the insert queries you're executing. Indeed, the query is always the same. Only the parameters change.

So, the code should look like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO malattia (nome, eta, ...) values (?, ?, ...)");
for (int i= 0; ...) {
    for (int j = 0; ...) {
        ps.setString(1, malattia);
        ps.setString(2, eta);
        ...
        ps.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use PreparedStatement and its Batch capability instead of plain query to simplify code and prevent SQL-injection.